# calling an actionlistener from another actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have an actionlistener that fires when I click a button lets call it box, I have another actionlistener for another button call it restart.  What I am trying to do is when I click a box button besides calling its own actionlistener inside of that actionlistener I want to call the actionlistener for restart when a certain condition is met.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could invoke

```
restart.doClick();
```

which will click the button which in turn will invoke the ActionListener.

Otherwise you can invoke the ActionListener directly by doing:

```
restartActionListener.actionPerformed( new ActionEvent(...) );
```